# Pandas round multiple columns with text

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
      A        B
0    13045.0   1.0
1    13056.0   15.0
2    Mobi      2.0
3    Mobi      3.0
4    15056.0   5.0
5    15068.0   1.0
```

I would to round the numeric values to 0, to end up with:

```
      A        B
0    13045   1
1    13056   15
2    Mobi    2
3    Mobi    3
4    15056   5
5    15068   1
```

I have tried df.round(0) and df['A'].round(0) to no avail. How does one ignore the text values when rounding a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `int` for create `int` column and then replace  with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
a = pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce')
df.A = df.A.mask(a.notnull(), a.fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
       A     B
0  13045   1.0
1  13056  15.0
2   Mobi   2.0
3   Mobi   3.0
4  15056   5.0
5  15068   1.0
```

Comment: I'm also trying to round column B. its dtype is float64. I've tried `np.round(df['B'])` as well as 'df['B']round()' but doesn't seem to work..

Comment: If need remove all `.0` need cast to `int`. So `df.B= df.B.astype(int)` works.